# Why is the dijit.popup not working correctly?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I take the following steps:

- Click 2 overlapping features from 2 different featLayers.
- Popup auto-selects and highlights map.infoWindow.features[first object]
- The popup content is actually from map.infoWindow.features[second object]

After you navigate to the second graphic and back, the popup corrects it's self??

here's an example using esri data:
http://jsfiddle.net/92Q2G/1/

Any advice?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Couple quick things --

1. I would say that your function identifyFeatures is getting 
   convoluted -- hard to follow. Break things down into smaller pieces and then set
   breakpoints as needed. Are the deferreds functioning the way you expect them?
2. You've probably already looked at this, but instead of keeping track
   of all your graphics, iterating through them, filtering and
   intersecting, maybe just use the identifyTask like in this example.
   It shows returning more than one feature identified in an infowindow
   http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/find_popup.html

Best of luck!

Comment: thanks for your comments. I'll have to take your #1 advice and re-check my identifyFeatures function. I really want to stay away from the identify Task since I'm using feature layers, and all the featLayer.graphics.features[0].attributes are already loaded in the map. Identify Task is more-so used for dynamic map service layers where attributes have to be retrieved from the REST service.

Comment: here's a workaround: setTimeout 500 mili before the infoWindow is displayed: http://jsfiddle.net/92Q2G/2/ still isn't 'correct' tho.